# UIView (or UILabel ?) with links to another View in the storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uilabel

I need to have a text part in my iOS application (in Objective C), with different names written. Each name must be **linked** to a view with the person's informations.

I don't know how to do that, what to use to be able to generate multiple links in one text, and link each name do the right action. So when I click on the link it should send the name I clicked on to required action.

Anyone knows how to do that with UIViews ? Or UILabels ? or anything..

Also, whenever I put a UIView in my View, it takes longer to load, do you know why ?

Thanks.. Hope that was clear enough !

HermyKa

Comment: Just use a UIButton, set the titleLabel to the name, and the action to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) for that,

Add this library in your code and than follow this step,

In .h file add this code

```
//Import RTLabel
#import "RTLabel.h"
// Add delegate
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<RTLabelDelegate>
@end
```

And in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    RTLabel *label = [[RTLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-262)/2, (self.view.frame.size.height-203)/2, 262, 203)];
    label.delegate = self;

    // You have to create link for each name
    NSString *searchString = @"<a href=\"Dilip\">Dilip</a> <a href=\"Dev\">Dev</a> <a href=\"Ram\">Ram</a>";
}

//RTLabel Delegate Method
- (void)rtLabel:(id)rtLabel didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    //When user click on one of the name this method will called and url will return the name which user has tapped. You can add condition on name that which view will display.
    NSLog(@"did tap on name %@", url);
}
```

Comment: Please dont post heavy work arounds where you can do the stuff with native UIElements.

Comment: @Mr.T this is helper site, we can provide any solution that can work, its users choice that which thing he should use. Also nothing is heavy work, its always on us.

Comment: @Mr.T And this is not right reason to downvote answer

Comment: It didnt answer the OP question. The OP was asking about a way to move around different views, and also a problem regarding a UIView load. I didnt find anything that answers the OP question.

Comment: @Mr.T i feel sorry if you didn't get how simple thing work, as you got the tap on name after that you can call any view or do anything, That is really simple, still i have added in my comment that just for you.

Comment: It doesnt make sense to create a long html string to achieve simple task. You should understand that OP is a newbie looking for simple solution.He may or may not have command over html or doesnt even know anything about delegates.BTW pls dont feel sorry.

Comment: @Mr.T, SO answer is not for only 1 user, its for full community, you cant tell when someone else will check this answer and find it use full, or same user will give it a try and its better(and as he needed) solution for him. Its always good thing to encourage newbie to try every way, If there issue in answer or its not doing what it says than you can raise issue with it, but saying that method is hard that just display your level of understanding that, again sorry for being rude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set of the UILabels with gesture recognizer connected to each. Or the set of UIButtons.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/104744/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-creating-custom-recognizers